# GIT and having multiple configuration files on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I have a development and production environments on Heroku, Both Apps use ClearDB but require unique credentials (i.e. 2 apps --> 2 DBs --> 2 unique credentials). We use a centralized Github repo to track all the changes and there are 3 people working on the project, with their own forks. The problem occurs when I have to constantly make sure that I don't overwrite the settings when pushing and merging code. There are 2 specific files and they have to be unique to each environment:

```
settings.php & connect.php --> localhost 
settings.php & connect.php --> Heroku dev
settings.php & connect.php --> Heroku production
```

I tried using `.gitignore` so I can have different settings in each file and not overwrite them on Github but that didn't work too well during testing.

I tried using `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` but it still keeps track of the changes.

What is the best practice when dealing with 3 different environments that require unique credentials but all working from the same repo?

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use environment variables

Heroku enables you to add environment variables to your dynos so that might be a good way to change environment-specific values.

In your `settings.php` you can pick those up using `getenv('variable_name')`.

2. Rename your files to `settings-production.php`, `settings-staging.php` etc. Ignore these files in git and before you `require()` the settings file, append `-{env}` based on the environment the script is in.

---

**PS:**
It seems your settings.php is staged, so you might need to unstage the file (and/or remove from previous commits)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful post. Sorry didn't accept your answer earlier.